# LINQ create generic lambda expression for Equals, GreaterThan, LessThan in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a method for adding a filter to an `IQueryable` using generic LINQ Expressions for the `Where` method. I've came up with one where I can compare 2 int values using the `Equal` method like this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> CreateWhereExpression<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> valueLeft, int valueLeft, int valueRight)
{
  var type = typeof(TEntity);
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
  var queryValueLeft = Expression.Constant(valueLeft);
  var queryValueRight = Expression.Constant(valueRight);
  var bodyExpression = Expression.Equal(queryValueLeft, queryValueRight); // Equal, GreaterThan, LessThan
  var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda(bodyExpression, parameter);
  var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
    new[] { type },
    query.Expression,
    whereExpression);

  return query.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

What I want is to create a filter for `GreaterThan` and `LessThan`, by replacing this:

```
var bodyExpression = Expression.Equal(queryValueLeft, queryValueRight);
```

into something like this (using Expressions):

```
var operationExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Expression), "Equal" ... );
```

or

```
var operationExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Expression), "GreaterThan" ... );
```

Depending on the operation.

I haven't been able to generate the correct Expression. The reason for this, is that the operation could come as a parameter for this method, but I don't want to use `if statements` or `switch`, which I have already made but want to change.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where did `Expression.Equal()` come from? Use `Expression.MakeBinary` and pass in the `ExpressionType`.

Comment: @NetMage and then I create a Lambda with that BinaryExpression?

Comment: Yes, just replace `Expression.Equal` with `Expression.MakeBinary` and pass in the type as a parameter to the method `CreateWhereExpression`.